# Dealing with function objects

Tags: c++, templates, higher-order-functions, function-object

`std::sort` is a template parameterized over a Compare class.  The function itself takes an object of that class as argument and "calls" it to compare elements of the to-be-sorted container.

I assume that it is important that we can give sort a concrete object, rather than simply let sort construct a Compare object itself.  (If not, please correct me.)

Now suppose that we want to implement a function `foo` that takes as input a `vector<T>` and a comparison function for `T`:

```
template <class T, class Compare>
bool foo(const vector<T>& v, Compare comp);
```

As part of this implementation we want to sort a different vector containing pairs of `T` and, say, `int`, i.e. sort a `vector<pair<T, int>>`.  But we want to sort this vector based on the `T` component only.  That means we want to lift the given order on `T` to an order on `pair<T, int>` and pass that one to `std::sort`.

How can this be done without using lambdas?  My problem is that I don't see a way to lift the `Compare` *object* for `T` to one for `pair<T, int>`.  I'm only able to lift the `Compare` *class* and then construct an object of that, which means that `foo` would completely ignore its `comp` argument.

Thanks.

Comment: *"`std::sort` is a template parameterized over a Compare class"* It is a template *type parameter*, it does not have to be a class. A function pointer type could also be used, for example.

Comment: @dyp: Thanks, but I wrote "without using lambdas".

Comment: Oops, I'm sorry. I somehow misread that in the opposite sense :(

Comment: Well, if you don't want to use lambdas, you can create a function object type manually (using a class template).

Comment: @dyp: Oh right, I think in that situation even my hack wouldn't work.

Comment: Yes, but how can you do that based on `comp`?

Comment: Here's a C++03 solution: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8b12193511d526ab In C++11, you can use a local type as shown by Vlad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May you define a local structure inside the function as for example?

```
template <class T, class Compare>

bool foo(const vector<T>& v, Compare comp)
{
   struct NewCompare
   {
      const Compare &rc;
      NewCompare( const Conpare &comp ) : rc( comp ) {}
      NewCompare( const NewCompare &comp ) : rc( comp.tc ) {}
      bool operator ()( const std::pair<T, int> &p1, const std::pair<T, int> &p2 ) const
      {
          return rc( p1.first, p2.first );
      }
    };

    //...
}
```

Or you can write a general functional adapter.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think of doing it locally.  But it would be nice to only need a single definition of lifting an order to the pair structure (e.g. as part of STL).  Following your solution requires me to essentially redefine it each time I need it.

Comment: @jingjok You can write a general functional adapter the same way.

Comment: Actually the locality there doesn't seem essential.  I realize now from your and dyp's code that the answer is to use state.

Comment: Presumably, the OP is stuck with C++03 (otherwise you'd use a lambda). In that case, the class can't be local, since local types couldn't be used as template arguments.